# Formatting JSON output

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to use 
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput

My PHP code is as follows

```
$data = array();
$result=$this->ArticleTag->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_article_tags where name LIKE '".$_GET['q']."%'");
foreach ($result as $row){
$name ='id:'.$row['tbl_article_tags'] ['id'].',name:'.$row['tbl_article_tags']['name'];
array_push($data, $name);   
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```

which gives me output as

```
["id :57, name :Editorial The Corporate","id :15, name :editorial","id :93, name :Editorial from abroad"]
```

I need to output JSON search results in the following format:

```
[
    {"id":"856","name":"House"},
    {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
    ...
]
```

I've tried different combination but didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try this:`  full code solution > your problem was in `$name` variable..

```
    $data = array();
    $result=$this->ArticleTag->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_article_tags where name LIKE '".$_GET['q']."%'");
    foreach ($result as $row){
    $name = array(
          'id' => $row['tbl_article_tags']['id'],
          'name' => $row['tbl_article_tags']['name']
           );
        $data[]=$name;   
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = array('id' => $row['tbl_article_tags']['id'], 'name' => $row['tbl_article_tags']['name']);
```

`json_encode` works with multidimensional arrays

Answer (score -1):

You can use 2 arrays so the values will be paired.

```php
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $tempArray = array(
            ['id'] = $row['tbl_article_tags'],
            ['name'] = $row['tbl_article_tags']['name']);
    array_push($data, $tempArray);   
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```